# compile code without running it

Tags: vb.net

im using visual basic 2010 express and i was wondering i there any way to compile a code without debugging it. Beacuse i have written some program that deletes temp files and stuff like that and i don't want to debug it on my main PC because i don't know if it works correctly (i have another PC where i test programs and stuff..) i haven't seen any "Compile without debugging" option or something like that..just green triangle saying "Start Debugging"
and yeah there is "build" option but that doesn't create an executable.

Comment: use the BUILD menu | Build Project which **does** create an executable for the selected configuration

Answer (score 2):

`Build >> Build Project`. Executable is located at `bin\Release`.

Comment: yeah but is there any difference between release and debug?

Comment: @user3425891  debug build will include debug symbols...the destination is actually either `bin\Release` or `bin\Debug` for AnyCPU; `x86\bin\Debug` or release for 32bit; or `x64\bin\Debug` or release for 64bit.  It depends on the selected configuration (Build menu | Configuration Manager)